# Getting unexpected results with MxN matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, matrix, indexing

I have this basic template matrix class:

```
template<class T, unsigned N>
class Matrix {
private:
    static const unsigned Stride = N;
    static const unsigned Size = Stride * Stride;
    T data[Size] = {};

public:
    Matrix() {};
    Matrix( const T* dataIn ) {
        fillMatrix( dataIn );
    }

    void fillMatrix( const T* dataIn );
    void printMatrix();
};

template<class T, unsigned N>
void Matrix<T, N>::fillMatrix( const T* dataIn ) {
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < Size; i++ ) {
        this->data[i] = dataIn[i];
    }
}

template<class T, unsigned N>
void Matrix<T, N>::printMatrix() {
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < Stride; i++ ) {
        for( unsigned int j = 0; j < Stride; j++ ) {
            std::cout << this->data[i*Stride + j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Which works fine! The data is populated correctly and it displays correctly. However, when I try to expand the above Square 2D Matrix to a MxN Matrix as such:

```
template<class T, unsigned M, unsigned N>
class Matrix {
private:
    static const unsigned Row = M;
    static const unsigned Col = N;
    static const unsigned Size = M * N;
    T data[Size] = {};

public:
    Matrix() {};
    Matrix( const T* dataIn ) {
        fillMatrix( dataIn );
    }

    void fillMatrix( const T* dataIn );
    void printMatrix();
};

template<class T, unsigned M, unsigned N>
void Matrix<T,M,N>::fillMatrix( const T* dataIn ) {
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < Size; i++ ) {
        this->data[i] = dataIn[i];
    }
}

template<class T, unsigned M, unsigned N>
void Matrix<T,M,N>::printMatrix() {
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < Row; i++ ) {
        for( unsigned int j = 0; j < Col; j++ ) {
            std::cout << this->data[i*Row + j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

I'm not getting the proper values: For example if I pass into this class template an array as such `double data[6] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };` With an instantiation of a `Matrix<double, 2,3>` to be a `2x3` Matrix I'm getting the values and printout as:

```
1 2 3
3 4 5
```

I would be expecting the data and output to be.

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

For some reason it is applying 3 twice and not adding 6 at all to the matrix.

Am I populating this MxN matrix wrong in the `fillMatrix()` function and or displaying it wrong by indexing in the `printMatrix()` function. I know this is fairly trivial but I'm overlooking this and can not seem to find what I'm missing.

---

**EDIT**

I was working with the debugger and looking at the class's member `data[Size]` and it was populated with the correct values, so this was leading me to think or suspect that the issue is within the `printMatrix()` function. Just as I was doing this a few users had posted useful answers! My logic seemed right at first but the ordering was wrong.

User: RandomBits's answer actually solves the issue.
User: Matthieu Brucher's answer explains the issue.

I would like to accept both answers but can only accept one. Thank you both for the informative information. I will leave this question open for now.

Comment: Fyi, if done correctly, you should be able to get pretty close to a 2D matrix using your 1D implementation just by doing `template<class T, size_t M, size_t N>
using Matrix2D = Matrix<Matrix<T,N>,M>;` or something similar.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm sure it can be done; but I'm using the later or 2nd Matrix to answer another question so I just wanted it to be simple. To answer their question the 2D square matrix isn't sufficient enough, so I was expanding it to be an arbitrary MxN matrix and I don't want to add confusion to using the first to create the later.

Answer (score 2):

The `double` vector you pass in has the elements in `C` order if you interpret it as a `2-d` array while your `print` function is printing the elements in `Fortran` order. Change `i*Row + j` to `i*Col+j`.

Comment: The print function is also C order, it's just that the index computation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong display. `i` is your row index, you need to multiply it with `Col`, not `Row`.

Think about the indices, `j` moves from 0 to `Col-1`, so when you move to another row, you need to increase the index according to this.

Comment: I was starting to lean towards that: when I checked the debugger the actual values are correct in the matrix as the member `data[Size]` does have the correct values. So this means it is in the print function and leaning me towards the indexing. Thank you!